# How To Implement Loading Screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I was wondering how can I implement a loading screen in my game. I have seen it in many popular games and I would like to add one. It's not just for fun but I have seen some slow loading times between scenes and would just like to add a smooth touch to the user experience instead of them thinking that their iDevice crashed.

Comment: You have to modify the launch screen. There are tutorials for that on the Internet.

Comment: @CeceXX No as in between scene's I want a loading screen sort of like a transititon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SKTransition`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKTransition_Ref/index.html) for that:

```
var transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(5)
self.view?.presentScene(yourScene, transition: transition)
```

This code fades out your old scene and smoothly loads the new one.
There are many different options available you could use instead of `fadeWithDuration`:

```
crossFadeWithDuration(_:)
doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration(_:)
doorsCloseVerticalWithDuration(_:)
doorsOpenHorizontalWithDuration(_:)
doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration(_:)
doorwayWithDuration(_:)
fadeWithColor(_:duration:)
flipHorizontalWithDuration(_:)
flipVerticalWithDuration(_:)
moveInWithDirection(_:duration:)
pushWithDirection(_:duration:)
revealWithDirection(_:duration:)
init(CIFilter:duration:)
```

Comment: This is fine for a scene that takes very little time to initialize. But if more resources are required for initialization then your app will pause when your scene is instantiated.  This is where something like a loading screen comes in